# How to trim spaces at the end of text?

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

In Google Sheets I have a column with email addresses of different lengths. At the end of each address are two additional spaces "  ".

I tried TRIM and it appears to work (no errors or anything in the new column) but the spaces are still there.

I downloaded to an xlsx file. Same result.

On both platforms I tried Find and Replace. Find "  " and Replace with "". Could not find any "  ".

I formatted text to plain text; still nothing. I have searched for hours here and on Google.

Comment: May I see your Excel file. I believe what you think as "space" is actually unprintable characters and have to be dealt accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The Clean() function may help to remove other artifacts, such as carriage returns, tabs, etc.

Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but when I paste special the value into a new cell it still have the two spaces...any other ideas?

Comment: The only reason I care is that when I copy paste an email address into the To: line on Apple Mail, it gives a dialog box that says "Looks like an invalid email address, want to send anyway". And it doesn't give me that box when I don't have the two spaces. I've tested sending emails to myself and it looks like they get delivered but not sure if it would work across the board.

Comment: Odd. How about doing something to remove the 2 spaces (" "s) with a formula like: Left(text, Len(text)-2), which would always remove those 2. Also, you might need to share examples or screenshots...

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I copy/pasted to a Doc and then did Find/Replace, "  " replace with "". That worked. So then I copied back into the spreadsheet.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it figured out! Best, Stephen

Answer (score 0):

These could be unbreakable spaces. If they are, you have to use:

```
SUBSTITUTE(XY, CHAR(160), "")
```